Combining data between the two of same document, but with different sets of information
Recently our MC server had become corrupted due to some, "misinformation", regarding our storage so we had to restore from a backup. Currently everything is doing alright, but we are trying to fix the advancements, as currently, they were somewhat wiped from most players. I have almost no experience in how to even remotely touch programming and .JSON, so I will need a lot of patience with this. Right now I am trying to take the corrupted file, the file from the day before, the file from right before, and the file after the crash and splice together all the values to get as many of the players advancements back. Each players access to their advancment is determined mainly by a true/false, so how would I combine the files so that all true values from before and after remain, as well as any false values?
I attempted the suggestion of doing parsing from our resident dev, but unfortunately I have no idea how to do it or execute it, and they are currently unavailible. I am mainly using this as a learning experience.

Hello, welcome on StackOverflow. I suggest you to take the [tour] and read [ask]. I understand your problem, but what do you mean with "corrupted file" ? can you show the content of some of them that is corrupted ? To check if you simply fix corrupted file and it's done

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
